# meteor client find is not working due to $eq

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I subscribed to my servers's publication as follows:

```
Template.observedQuestions.onCreated(function(){
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function(){
        self.subscribe('observedQuestionsFeed');
    });
});
```

Now I need to fetch my data using helper function:

```
Template.observedQuestions.helpers({
    observedQuestionsList : function(){
        questions =  Questions.find({
                     observedByUsers : {$exists: true,$elemMatch:{$eq:Meteor.userId()}}});
        return questions;

    }
});
```

but it does not work due to $eq being not recognised in minimongo.
How to solve it?

doc sample:

```
{
    "_id" : "rP4JP8jkprwwi3ZCp",
    "qUserId" : "NLLW3RBXqnbSGuZ3n",
    "type" : "question",
    "date" : ISODate("2016-02-13T11:23:10.845Z"),
    "subject" : "test",
    "question" : "test",
    "replies" : [ 
        { 
            "rID" : "LphcqKnkTHf25SCwq",
            "rUserID" : "NLLW3RBXqnbSGuZ3n",
            "date" : ISODate("2016-02-13T11:23:10.847Z"), 
            "answer" : "reply1."
        }, 
        { 
            "rID" : "HxaohnEgxwNJLtf2z", 
            "rUserID" : "NLLW3RBXqnbSGuZ22", 
            "date" : ISODate("2016-02-13T11:23:10.848Z"), 
            "answer" : "reply2" 
        } 
    ], 
    "observedByUsers" : [ "Bi24LGozvtihxFrNe" ] 
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample document of your `Questions` collection?

Comment: Why don't you use `Questions.find({observedByUsers: Meteor.userId()});`?

Comment: Exactly, this would find the right documents even if there were more userIds in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your sample `Questions` document, the field `observedByUsers` is a simple array which contains user IDs.

As a result, you could simply use the following query:

```
Questions.find({observedByUsers: Meteor.userId()});
```